# Options Missing from File browser

Tags: uv, interface, file-browser

This has happened before, but I can't figure out how to fix it. Where are the options for the UV layout export that are usually on the left side of the screen?
[image: Missing UV Export Options]

Comment: Try using T button

Answer (score 3):

To show or hide Options tab in export window use <kbd>T</kbd> button while mouse cursor located inside the window. Alternatively you can click <kbd>+</kbd> icon that was added in blender version 2.74 next to the File Path input.

[image]